# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE after first quit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router

I have set up a React app with React router. My app starts up fine and so far there have been no problems on with what I have built on the front-end, but when I do the first quit I get the following error. I have followed suggestions from previous posts and tried npm install a few times, but I continue to get this error when I first quit the app. On the router side, I have a package.json, a yarn.lock, and a package-lock.json. On other React projects I have done, I'm not seeing a package-lock.json, so I don't know if this is causing the problem? I'm pretty new to coding, so any help you can give me is much appreciated.

Note: I have already tried the commands, but it does not resolve the issue for getting this error after I quit the router.

Step 1: npm cache clean --force

Step 2: delete node_modules folder

Step 3: npm install

Here is the code:

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start:dev: `concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sarabroad/.npm/_logs/2018-08-30T00_26_56_073Z-debug.log

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: I'm running on macOS High Sierra. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your version of NPM is up to date `npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: I ran npm install -g npm@latest, but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: What are you using to set up reactjs?

Comment: I used create-react-app projectname for the front-end and yarn add axios react-router-dom. After I did the react router install, I manually created a package.json (I'm not sure if this is standard practice). Also, when I just had the front-end I would have to cd into the client folder I made to house all the front-end code, but then I yarn start from the root folder now that the react router is added. My client file is like my "view" file in MVC. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong! Thank you!